# Invalid bracketing error while executing a query with excel

Tags: c#, sql, excel

My Query is this.

> **SELECT [Recon. Account]  FROM [Sheet1$] WHERE something = 'YES'**

Error Coming ::

> Invalid bracketing of name '[Recon. Account]'.

I have been using this same format with the other queries too and they all are working fine.
What i think bothering me is that **dot** in that word "**Recon. Account**". 
Thanks.

Comment: I am able to execute it successfully after removing the DOT.

But i want it to be run with the same name              [Recon. Account]

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT [Recon].[Account] FROM [Sheet1$] WHERE something = 'YES'
```

Use brackets only around column or table names but not around both.

Comment: Well its not working either, giving me this error.

Invalid use of '.', '!', or '()'. in query expression '[Recon]. [Account]'.

Comment: And Recon. Account is a single column Name

Comment: Oh, didn't know that. Then try removing the blank right before the point in your query like this: `SELECT [Recon.Account] FROM [Sheet1$] WHERE something = 'YES'`

Comment: @juergen d I too faced this problem. Still issue exists after removed the blank right before the point.